# perforce command to know the non versioned files

Tags: linux, svn, command, version, perforce

I am new to perforce. i have client created in linux.
and synced all the files from the repository. previously we were using svn to add and delete files to a repository.
in svn we have a command to know the status of the tree by "svn st" which shows all the local modifications(with symbol M) and also the non versioned files(with symbol ?).
i want to know what is the equivalnet command for this in perforce which shows all the non versioned files also.
Could anyone please help me with th command in linux.

Answer (score 4):

In Perforce changes that have been "opened" (using P4 terminology) are attached to changelists.  To list the changelists use the [changes command](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r13.1/manuals/cmdref/changes.html):

`p4 changes`

To see the changes attached to a specific changelist use the [change command](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r13.1/manuals/cmdref/change.html):

`p4 change -o $CHANGELIST`

The [status command](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r13.1/manuals/cmdref/status.html) without any options will preview files that are added, deleted or modified but that haven't been opened (which really means haven't been attached to a changelist).

`p4 status`

The status command or the [reconcile command](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r13.1/manuals/cmdref/reconcile.html) can also be used to "open" the changes.  Note that the status command will of course exclude files you have ignored.  If you want to see them use the `-I` option.